# How to check keyboard language with python

Tags: python-2.7

I need this to determine local/computer language (e.g., the language that is read from the screen)
EDIT: Like the language used for displaying text to the user on-screen.

Comment: What is the context? People can read multiple languages and most modern systems can display multiple languages (Unicode). Do you want to know the current locale, Accept-Language http header, GUI language settings, something else? My phone keyboard allows to input emoji characters -- is it a language for your purposes?

Comment: Sorry, like the GUI locale language. I'll edit it to clear up confision